# How to get Invoke-Command verbose or debug output from a PowerShell command in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, invoke-command

I have a PowerShell command that invokes a command on a remote machine to print out a debug message, and then prints out a debug message on the running machine, as follows:

```
function Start-DebugTest {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param ()

    $cmd = {
        $DebugPreference = 'Continue'
        Write-Debug -Message 'This is invoked DEBUG message'
    }

    $params = @{
        ComputerName = $ip
        Credential = $cred
        ScriptBlock = $cmd
    }

    Invoke-Command @params

    Write-Debug -Message 'This is a normal DEBUG message'
}
```

When I run the `Start-DebugTest` command locally I see the following output:

```
DEBUG: This is invoked DEBUG message
DEBUG: This is a normal DEBUG message
```

When I run this through C# like this:

```
using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
{
    var command = powershell.AddCommand("Start-DebugTest");
    powershell.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("DebugPreference", "Continue");

    PSDataCollection<PSObject> output = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();
            output.DataAdded += (sender, args) => DataAdded((PSDataCollection<PSObject>) sender, progress);
    powershell.Streams.Debug.DataAdded += (sender, args) => StreamDataAdded((PSDataCollection<DebugRecord>) sender, args, "DEBUG", progress);

    var resources = await Task.Factory.FromAsync(
         powershell.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, output),
         asyncResult => powershell.EndInvoke(asyncResult));

    return resources;
}

private void StreamDataAdded<T>(PSDataCollection<T> records, DataAddedEventArgs e, string msgType, IProgress<string> progress) where T : InformationalRecord
{
    string msg = records[e.Index].Message;
    progress.Report($"{msgType}: {msg}");
}

private void DataAdded(PSDataCollection<PSObject> myp, IProgress<string> progress)
{
    Collection<PSObject> results = myp.ReadAll();
    foreach (PSObject result in results)
    {
        progress.Report($"OUTPUT: {result.ToString()}");
    }
}
```

I only receive the debug message running on the local machine and not the one from the invoked command, from either of the `DataAdded` events:

```
DEBUG: This is a normal DEBUG message
```

If I see the output when running it locally, somehow the debug message is available. Is there any way to access it from C#?

Comment: The problem is the example isn't ready to test.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you probably have to specify your debug preference on the `Invoke-Command` call...

## [about_Preference_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-5.1)

> The preference variables affect the PowerShell operating environment and all commands run in the environment.

The key point here is ***"in the environment"***

The command running on the other environment doesn't share the same preference setting as the calling command.

## [about_CommonParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-5.1)

`-Debug[:{$true | $false}]`

> Displays programmer-level detail about the operation performed by the command. This parameter works only when the command generates a debugging message. For example, this parameter works when a command contains the Write-Debug cmdlet.

## Solution

```
$params = @{
    ComputerName = $ip
    Credential = $cred
    ScriptBlock = $cmd
    Debug = $true
}

Invoke-Command @params
```